# How do I print a set of sheets to PDF in Excel 2002?

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I've tried CutePDF, but programmatic access needs to happen via registry entries, which isn't thread safe.  I've also tried PDF Writer, but program has serious problems when multiple users are logged into the same machine trying to print at the same time.

I'm looking for an easy C# or VBA command to which i can say -- print this .xls, and it does it without me having to jump through hoops.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be in for a hard search there. Most of the "Source to PDF" converters are based on the print stream, where you print whatever you want into a standard printstream which is wrapped/converted to PDF. And the printstream(spooler) is very async (not threadsafe) and prone to problems with multiple users on the same machine.

There are a very few programmatically solutions out there and I think they all cost money, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you might use Open Office -- the export as pdf works quite nicely in writer. 
Maybe Calc has similar support?

Also see other answers tagged openoffice.org

for instance [openoffice-command-line-pdf-creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355447/openoffice-command-line-pdf-creation)