# Convert Office files to swf (Flash)

Tags: linux, excel, ms-word, flash

In a webbapp hosted on its private server with Linux(Ubuntu Server 10) , the users will upload documents(MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF, etc..). We want to convert the files in SWF(Flash) objects , to embed them to the site. I saw a lot of Websites having this future. How they do it ?

Comment: Which web sites have this feature? I couldn't really find many except for the MS Live Docs site.

Comment: I don't see how they can be converted into Flash files exactly. I mean, SWF and DOC are not really compatible file types; they're totally different. Perhaps what you're looking for is something that can convert the files to HTML or XML which could in turn be used inside a SWF (or just about any other way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of server side apps that can convert from DOC, PPT, etc to SWF format (trying searching for "PPT to SWF"). As you're using linux, then have a look at running openOffice. If you need to manipulate the content eg browse through slides in a PPT then have a look at a some of the commercial solutions that comes with an API.

Comment: I searched before for libraries , but I did not find any useful library to acomplish my task. Do you know a working library? I can`t use OpenOffice because the server is Ubuntu Server Edition ( no GUI)

Comment: I'm not aware of any AS libraries. There are a host of third party apps that you can upload your document to and then convert it on the server via a command line script.

Comment: Here's some open office info that might be useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355447/openoffice-command-line-pdf-creation