# .NET graphic libraries to display images (pdf, .docx and any other format of image) in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a ASP .NET MVC application where users are able to upload files to a repository. Those files could be pdf, doc, any type of image and so on.

When the user select a file to be imported I would like to display this file in the browser so they can review its contents before the upload.

I know I could use some sort of IFrame to display pdf but I am looking for some specific class or .net libraries to implement this feature.

I just need a north.

Comment: I never cease to learn something new. pdf and docx are images now?

Comment: The formats themselves might not be images, but I can just imagine a component that would take the file, and "print" the contents to an image. No idea if such a product exists, but I can see where @Dimas is coming from.

Comment: Why not just download the files to the user's PC and let the user look at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult problem.  There are some libraries that can help.  For instance PDF files might be rendered to images with [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/).  Word and Excel files might be converted to PDF or image with a number of libraries.  None of them, AFAIK, are very good at it so I can not recommend one.

You could automate MSO to perform the conversion to PDF, but that is decidedly not safe for server code.  Another possibility is convert source documents to SWF files (like [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com)) and display in flash.  There are some great libraries out there, but it will limit your supported clients.  Sharepoint has support for providing some of this capability as well.  Others have used [OpenOffice to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355447/openoffice-command-line-pdf-creation) MSO documents but also at a loss of quality.

I can't really advise any specific direction as it is highly dependent on what you/your company is willing to spend and the desired results.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to rely on Windows and the explorer thumbnails for it, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918586/windows-api-code-pack-thumbnail-gives-preview-thumb-of-pdf-but-not-word-or-excel), but then you'd have to make sure that:

1. You can abuse the server in the most elaborate way (install stuff, talk to the shell from ASP.NET)
2. You have a thumbnail provider installed on the server for every type that you want to preview. I guess from the moment you can see the thumbnail in explorer, you're set. So for pdf, you might need to install PDF Reader from Adobe.
3. Docx files should be saved with thumbnail checked (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918586/windows-api-code-pack-thumbnail-gives-preview-thumb-of-pdf-but-not-word-or-excel)). There seems to be no other easy, free way to convert a docx to a thumbnail. The "best" solution I came across, was saving it automatically again somehow, and making sure the thumbnail option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to say that's impossible, but it can't be done with finite effort.

What you are asking for is a browser-based solution, because you want the user to be able to "review" the document **before** uploading.

Therefore you cannot use a server side solution, which is essentially what is being asked by referring to a ".Net library".

.Net libraries are dependent on an installed version of .Net, which does not exist in all versions for all operating systems for which graphical browsers exist.

Next, recent changes in browser security do not allow to read the full client-side file name of the selected file in the input field.

You'd have to rely on HTML5 and its FileReader to access the file's byte stream, but even then you can only retrieve image from image files. ([see sample](http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/))

Excluding browser-based solutions in Flash, ActiveX, Java, due to browser and platform support, this leaves JavaScript as the only "reasonable" solution: you'd need a library for each supported format to either convert a file into an image in an image format supported by browsers, or extract the text(+image) representation of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Great awnsers... Just want to share the result of my research and I found a nice client-based solution supported by Mozilla Labs. This is a framework based on HTML5 and Javascript with no native code needed.

Here the project website:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

This is what you are capable of:
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

And for the last a great video explaning how everthing works
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv15UY-4Fg8&noredirect=1

Reguarding my question we are going to converter every possible file to PDF on the server and then render this PDF using this framework.