# How to show a preview of an uploaded document in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form where I take basic Resume information from user and then there is an upload button for Resume upload. Now I want to have a "Detail" page where I can show the details of user inputs for the Resume form. I am able to show all the Model properties except the (uploaded file). Is there some way I can show some sort of preview pane for document uploaded in the Detail page.

ViewModel:

```
public class ResumeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Resume Name.")]
    [Display(Name = "Resume Name")]
    public string ResumeName { get; set; }

    [FileType("pdf|doc|docx|PDF", ErrorMessage = "File type is not valid.")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Upload Resume")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedResume { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, I am able to download the document with below code

```
   public FileContentResult Download(int? resumeId)
        {
            var temp = _context.Resumes.Where(f => f.ResumeId == resumeId).SingleOrDefault();
            var fileRes = new FileContentResult(temp.Content.ToArray(), temp.ContentType);
            fileRes.FileDownloadName = temp.FileName;
            return fileRes;
        }
```

But how to display it in some page along with rest of the Model properties?

Comment: Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869654/net-graphic-libraries-to-display-images-pdf-docx-and-any-other-format-of-ima) for a few options

Comment: Does not seem like something straight forward. :-|

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can't I use I frame or something to show small preview window and all. Just wondering.

Comment: I do not want entire webpage to display the doc. Just small scrollable area in web page.

Comment: Might be an option, but why do you want to do this? (you have already effectively sent the document to the client anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes you are right. I thought if it was simply few line of code, I will learn something new. Nevermind, there are plenty of other things to learn too. :) Besides, it's my home project, so it's not a mandatory requirement.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I found one link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439634/view-pdf-as-part-of-the-page  it tells that I need to use `FileStream("c:\\PeterPDF2.pdf",...` ). Can I do something like this. But what shall I put inplace of `c:\\PeterPDF2.pdf`

Comment: You should be able to just use the code you currently have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152887/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with object tag

firstly create a page to view uploadedfile

cshtml

```
<object data='@Url.Action("GetFile")' type="@Viewbag.Type" width="700" height="700"></object>
```

and in the FileController

```
     public ActionResult Index(int? resumeId)
                {               

                  var temp = _context.Resumes.Where(f => f.ResumeId == 
                  resumeId).SingleOrDefault();
                  var fileRes = new FileContentResult(temp.Content.ToArray(), 
                  temp.ContentType);
                  Session["Path"]= temp.FileName;
                  Session["Type"]=temp.ContentType
                  return View();
                }
and Action of File

public ActionResult GetFile()
        {
            if (Session["Path"] != null)
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new          
                FileStream(Session["Path"].ToString(), FileMode.Open, 
                FileAccess.Read);
                ViewBag.Type=Session["Type"]
                return File(fileStream, Session["Type"]);
            }
            return View("NotFound");
        }
```