# Convert ODT to PDF with Openoffice on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, openoffice-writer, odt

I have many .odt files in my Windows system. I would like to convert these files to PDF. I tried that in command line

soffice.bin --headless -convert-to pdf:"writer_pdf_Export" c:\MyOdtFile.odt

But, It does not work. This method can only open file, does not convert! 
How can I do this?

Comment: Would it be an option to use libreoffice instead of OpenOffice? LO supports command-line pdf conversion out of the box.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/355447/342546

Comment: Yes, I can use LO instead of Openoffice. In fact, I installed it portable version and normal version after your commet. But It does not work. I tried using that command : soffice.bin --headless -conver-to:pdf:"writer_pdf_Export" c:\Myfile.odt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LibreOffice, the following command should work:

> `soffice.exe --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir <output directory> <file1.odt> <file2.odt>`

When converting to pdf, `-convert-to pdf` is sufficient. The `--outdir` parameter is optional; if you don't use it, the PDF will be created in the current working directory. Using `soffice.bin` didn't work for me (missing sal3.dll), but `soffice.exe` works (LibreOffice 4.2.4.2, Win 7). If `soffice.exe` isn't in your path, you would have to set the PATH explicitly or add the complete path to the command above:

> ' "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe" --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir C:\temp test1.odt`

Make sure that **LO isn't running** when issuing the convert command - otherwise the conversion will fail without an error message.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @tohuwawohu's answer... he wrote:

> Make sure that **LO isn't running** when issuing the convert command - otherwise the conversion will fail without an error message.

This can be eliminated by adding another parameter to the command line:

```
-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}"
```

This creates a new environment for `${USER}`'s headless instance of LibreOffice, should he have already a not-headless, GUI one running.

This way, the headless instance will not conflict with the already running instance.

Comment: How about multiple instances of LO? Do you need to change temp file path for each instance?

Comment: @AkashKava: Yes. (But I never tried to run multiple headless instances as the same user....)